# Problem with optimization of a function which contains a "for-loop"

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

I am trying to optimize a function in MATLAB which has a `for`-loop in it. I tried different codes but didn't get any results and can't figure out where is the problem.

here is the function:

```
function U2 = least1(ydata,xdata,x,y1,w,A,sz,yprime,y) 
for i=1:1:1000 
    U2(1,i) = sum((sqrt(1+yprime.^2)).*(A(1) * exp(-y/A(2))*(1 - exp(-ydata(i)/A(2)))...
           + A(3) * exp(-y/A(4))*(exp(-ydata(i)/A(4))-1)).*w);     
 end
end
```

All the variables are available I just need to optimize it to get the perfect match of `A`.
 I tried to solve it with the problem-based optimization as the codes below :
but instead of four values for `A`, I get 
-Inf
-Inf
-Inf
-Inf

```
A = optimvar('A',4);
potential = fcn2optimexpr(@least1,A);
obj = sum((potential - u1).^2);
prob = optimproblem('Objective',obj);
x0.A = [11.959,0.069,3.53,4.118*10^(-3)];
show(prob)
sol =  solve(prob,x0)
```

please let me know if anything is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizer does not now what to do with the other inputs of `least1(ydata,xdata,x,y1,w,A,sz,yprime,y)`.

You need to tell it the values when you assign it as a cost function, i.e.

```
@(A) least1(ydata,xdata,x,y1,w,A,sz,yprime,y)
```

The keyword is *anonymous function handle* (what you have just is just a *function handle*.

I am pretty irritated by the way you are setting up the optimization problem (maybe that is a new way?).

I would have made it straight forward this way:

```
% anonymous function handle to original function
fnc_ogl = @(A) least1(ydata,xdata,x,y1,w,A,sz,yprime,y) -u1;
% create least-squares cost function (you need to have a single cost value
% for fminsearch)
fnc_cst = @(A) sum( fnc_ogl.^2 );
% initial guess
A0 = [11.959,0.069,3.53,4.118*10^(-3)]
% call unconstrained local optimization
[A_opt, fval, exitflag] = fminsearch(fnc,A0)
```

BTW

1. you should allocate the size of `U2` beforehand with `U2 = NaN(1,1000)` to speed up the cost function
2. Your example does not work as all inputs to `least1` are missing
3. `least1` does not use the variables `xdata`, `x`, `y1`, and `sz`

.

Comment: thank you very much for your guidance, I want to do the optimization based on minimizing non-linear least square method. therefore, I used this line 'obj = sum((potential - u1).^2);' . in the end, the results should be the best matching values of 'A' that provides the best matching line to the 'u1' values and the potential values that are calculated from the function 'least1'. please let me know if you have any idea in mind to add the 'u1' values to the optimization.

Comment: You can simply add this to `fnc_ogl` (as I just did). The *[anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)* (structure`@(x)...x`) pretends that all variables, which are not inside the brackets `@( )` to be constants of the value that they have when the *anonymous function* is defined (so in this line of code). This makes your function with 10 parameters `least1(...) - u1` to be a function with a single parameter (which is `A` in the answer code above and `x` in the snippet of this comment)